# How to recover a 'dead' Linux VM on Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure

I have/had a VM running Ubuntu on Azure. After one resize of the instance, it stopped responding completely; i can't SSH in and the web server is not responding. What's more, the New Relic server monitor agent doesn't appear to be sending data, so it looks like the machine is not running at all or is completely disconnected from the internet (even though the Azure dashboard says everything's fine). 
One thing I tried is snapshoting it and creating a new instance from the snapshot, but it didn't change anything.
Are there any other options to recover the machine?

Answer (score 0):

If you think that the VM is not responding, shutdown the VM and delete the Role for the VM. This will detach the VHD for the VM. Now you can use any tool like Cloud Storage Studio to download the VHD locally and test it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try resizing the CPU in the portal, which will likely bounce the machine to a new host. That could also resolve your issue.